# C# ANTLR4 DefaultErrorStrategy or custom error listener does not catch unrecognized characters

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

It's quite strange, but `DefaultErrorStrategy` does not do anything for catching unrecognized characters from a stream. I tried a custom error strategy, a custom error listener and `BailErrorStrategy` - no luck here.

My grammar

```
grammar Polynomial;

parse           : canonical EOF
                ;

canonical       : polynomial+                                     #canonicalPolynom
                | polynomial+ EQUAL polynomial+                   #equality
                ;

polynomial      : SIGN? '(' (polynomial)* ')'                     #parens
                | monomial                                        #monom
                ;

monomial        : SIGN? coefficient? VAR ('^' INT)?               #addend
                | SIGN? coefficient                               #number
                ;

coefficient             : INT | DEC;

INT                     : ('0'..'9')+;
DEC                     : INT '.' INT;
VAR                     : [a-z]+;
SIGN                    : '+' | '-';
EQUAL                   : '=';
WHITESPACE              : (' '|'\t')+ -> skip;
```

and I'm giving an input `23*44=12` or `@1234`

I'm expecting that my parser throws mismatched token or any kind of exception for a character `*` or `@` that is not defined in my grammar.

Instead, my parser just skips `*` or `@` and traverse a tree like there are do not exist.

My handler function where I'm calling lexer, parser and that's kind of stuff.

```
private static (IParseTree tree, string parseErrorMessage) TryParseExpression(string expression)
        {
            ICharStream stream = CharStreams.fromstring(expression);
            ITokenSource lexer = new PolynomialLexer(stream);

            ITokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
            PolynomialParser parser = new PolynomialParser(tokens);

            //parser.ErrorHandler = new PolynomialErrorStrategy(); -> I tried custom error strategy
            //parser.RemoveErrorListeners();
            //parser.AddErrorListener(new PolynomialErrorListener()); -> I tried custom error listener
            parser.BuildParseTree = true;

            try
            {
                var tree = parser.canonical();
                return (tree, string.Empty);
            }
            catch (RecognitionException re)
            {
                return (null, re.Message);
            }
            catch (ParseCanceledException pce)
            {
                return (null, pce.Message);
            }
        }
```

I tried to add a custom error listener.

```
public class PolynomialErrorListener : BaseErrorListener
    {
        private const string Eof = "EOF";

        public override void SyntaxError(TextWriter output, IRecognizer recognizer, IToken offendingSymbol, int line, int charPositionInLine, string msg,
            RecognitionException e)
        {
            if (msg.Contains(Eof))
            {
                throw new ParseCanceledException($"{GetSyntaxErrorHeader(charPositionInLine)}. Missing an expression after '=' sign");
            }

            if (e is NoViableAltException || e is InputMismatchException)
            {
                throw new ParseCanceledException($"{GetSyntaxErrorHeader(charPositionInLine)}. Probably, not closed operator");
            }

            throw new ParseCanceledException($"{GetSyntaxErrorHeader(charPositionInLine)}. {msg}");
        }

        private static string GetSyntaxErrorHeader(int errorPosition)
        {
            return $"Expression is invalid. Input is not valid at {--errorPosition} position";
        }
    }
```

After that, I tried to implement a custom error strategy.

```
public class PolynomialErrorStrategy : DefaultErrorStrategy
    {
        public override void ReportError(Parser recognizer, RecognitionException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }

        public override void Recover(Parser recognizer, RecognitionException e)
        {
            for (ParserRuleContext context = recognizer.Context; context != null; context = (ParserRuleContext) context.Parent) {
                context.exception = e;
            }

            throw new ParseCanceledException(e);
        }

        public override IToken RecoverInline(Parser recognizer)
        {
            InputMismatchException e = new InputMismatchException(recognizer);
            for (ParserRuleContext context = recognizer.Context; context != null; context = (ParserRuleContext) context.Parent) {
                context.exception = e;
            }

            throw new ParseCanceledException(e);
        }

        protected override void ReportInputMismatch(Parser recognizer, InputMismatchException e)
        {
            string msg = "mismatched input " + GetTokenErrorDisplay(e.OffendingToken);
            // msg += " expecting one of " + e.GetExpectedTokens().ToString(recognizer.());
            RecognitionException ex = new RecognitionException(msg, recognizer, recognizer.InputStream, recognizer.Context);
            throw ex;
        }

        protected override void ReportMissingToken(Parser recognizer)
        {
            BeginErrorCondition(recognizer);
            IToken token = recognizer.CurrentToken;
            IntervalSet expecting = GetExpectedTokens(recognizer);
            string msg = "missing " + expecting.ToString() + " at " + GetTokenErrorDisplay(token);
            throw new RecognitionException(msg, recognizer, recognizer.InputStream, recognizer.Context);
        }
    }
```

Is there any flag that I forgot to specify in a parser or I have incorrect grammar?

Funny thing that I'm using ANTLR plugin in my IDE and when I'm testing my grammar in here this plugin correctly responds with `line 1:2 token recognition error at: '*'`

Full source code: https://github.com/EvgeniyZ/PolynomialCanonicForm

I'm using ANTLR 4.8-complete.jar

**Edit**

I tried to add to a grammar rule

```
parse           : canonical EOF
                ;
```

Still no luck here

Comment: Remember there are two recognizers here: a lexer and a parser. Each can have an error listener added. Your code adds a listener for the parser, but you don't add one for the lexer (see CanonicalFormer.cs). So, it'll run the default for the lexer. Both default error handlers are quite primitive. Also, you should use Antlr4BuildTasks for builds that use Antlr.Runtime.Standard, i.e., in Polynomial.WebApi.csproj. Just search for Antlr4BuildTasks and read the instructions. --Ken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you do this:

```
parse
 : canonical EOF
 ;
```

and also invoke this rule:

```
var tree = parser.parse();
```

By adding the `EOF` token (end of input), you are forcing the parser to consume all tokens, which should result in an error when the parser cannot handle them properly.

> Funny thing that I'm using ANTLR plugin in my IDE and when I'm testing my grammar in here this plugin correctly responds with `line 1:2 token recognition error at: '*'`

That is what the lexer emits on the `std.err` stream. The lexer just reports this warning and goes its merry way. So the lexer just ignores these chars and therefor never end up in the parser. If you add the following line at the end of your lexer:

```
// Fallback rule: matches any single character if not matched by another lexer rule
UNKNOWN : . ;
```

then the `*` and `@` chars will be sent to the parser as `UNKNOWN` tokens and should then cause recognition errors.

Comment: Yeah, thank you for the suggestion, I saw this advice earlier in a github, unfortunately,
it didn't work for me.
I added this rule to the grammar, but DefaultErrorStrategy does not throw any mismatched errors.
BailErrorStrategy works a bit better but didn't cover ```@123``` or ```12*44=12``` cases.

I can for sure make a hack with custom regexp validation of the input, but in other resources about antlr4 validation should work just fine.


my commit with changes -  https://github.com/EvgeniyZ/PolynomialCanonicForm/commit/387def3cc81abaa5bfe3f5421c43f10c1c4ce917

Comment: I'll have a closer look later on. Have you added your complete grammar to your question? If I copy-paste it, I see the same things happening as you do?

Comment: Yes, I double-checked it, it's complete grammar.

Link to a grammar in github - [grammar](https://github.com/EvgeniyZ/PolynomialCanonicForm/blob/master/Polynomial.WebApi/Domain/Grammar/Polynomial.g4)


Could it be an issue with ANTLR4 generating to C# ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, ```UNKNOWN : . ;``` does work for me.
I'm curious - it's a special lexer name rule for grammar mismatching?

Comment: No, you can name it whatever you like (`OTHER`, `ANY`, ...). Without it, the lexer just ignores the character (which is why the parser does not produce an error). With the `UNKNOWN` rule, the parser suddenly has to cope with this `UNKNOWN` token (which it can't, and produces an error).

Comment: ok, but why it's not throwed as RecognitionException?
in my ```PolynomialErrorListener.SyntaxError()``` method it contains only msg, but exception is null

Comment: Because that listener is attached to your parser, not the lexer.